# Delete selected element from my gridView

Tags: java, android, gridview

How can I remove the selected item on my gridView list?
Now I delete my last added element.

```
 @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            remove(personItems);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

i try do like this

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    personItems = getItem(position);
...
public void onClick(View view) {
            personItems.remove(position);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

but in this way i can t delete element from my grid view

Full code of my adapter

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<PersonItems> {

PersonItems personItems;

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView member_name;
    ImageView profile_pic;
}

public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<PersonItems> users) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_item, users);
}


@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    personItems = getItem(position);
    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
        viewHolder.member_name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.member_name);
        viewHolder.profile_pic = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.profile_pic);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    viewHolder.member_name.setText(personItems.name);
    viewHolder.profile_pic.setImageResource(setImage());

    Button buttonDelete = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.buttonDelete);
    buttonDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            remove(personItems);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
    return convertView;
}

public int setImage() {
    switch (personItems.getName()) {
        case Names.AII:
            return R.drawable.profile;
        case Names.VdV:
            return R.drawable.vdm;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

}

Comment: get the position of selected item and id of associated view

Comment: @gaurav 
updated question

Comment: can you share full adapter code

Comment: can you share the error you are getting

Comment: @PhanVanLinh done

Comment: @gaurav i haven t error, i delete element but only last which i add in my list. But i need delete selected element.

Comment: `notifyItemRemoved(personItems);` `notifyDataSetChanged();` 
        `notifyItemRangeChanged();` try adding these

Comment: @gaurav cannot resolve 1 and 3 method ...

Comment: in 3rd option pass the position and size of your list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your adapter's constructor receive the list view from your Activity:

```
MyCustomAdapter adapter = new MyCustomAdapter(context, mylist);
```

Your adapter's constructor should look like this:

```
public MyCustomAdapter (Context context, List<Object> objectsList){
    this.objectsList = objectsList;
    this.context = context;    
}
```

Now in your getView() method:

```
Button buttonDelete = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.buttonDelete);
buttonDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        objectsList.remove(position);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

get the postion of current grid view and perform the delete method

Comment: get your current adapter position by using

  int postion=getAdapterPosition();